# Problem facing in adding folder having space

Tags: svn

I have an unversioned folder "Data Files" in D:\test\prototype\AtlasTools\Transforms\SxS\src\ folder.

I need to add these folder using commandline. I used the following code to add:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2*" %i in (`svn status ^| findstr /r "^\?"`) do svn add "%i"
```

But it is showing error like "SxS\src\Data cannot be found. Actually my folder name is "Data Files".

How can I add a folder having space in it?

Comment: Ah ... the problems that people get themselves into with spaces in filenames.  Just don't do it!

Answer (score 2):

Does it work if you enclose the folder name in quotes? (that's the *entire* pathname including the folder)

Apart from that, I tend to agree with [Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c) that spaces in folder names will, sooner or later, come back and bite you.

Comment: Great! So when the time comes to accept an answer, you'll know what to do, won't you? ;-D

Answer (score 1):

Escape the space with a backslash.

or

If you want a directory with a name that has a space in it, such as "My Files" you need include the command in " ".

Comment: how can i escape the space in 

 for /f "usebackq tokens=2*" %i in (svn status ^| findstr /r "^\?") do svn add "%i"

i am new to this type area....

Answer (score 0):

for /f "usebackq tokens=2*" %i in (`svn status ^| findstr /r "^\?"`) do svn add "%i %j"

this is the solution for this...

Comment: Try doubling up the % so `%i` becomes `%%i`. I haven't tried this myself, but I found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1073159/2085526