# svn add all folder with space issue

Tags: svn

I'm trying to make a bash script in my debian to update all files in a svn checkout from my workspace. Within this script I also need to add all new files/folders that might exist. For this I tried

```
svn add --force .
```

but I get an error:
svn: E125001: '/home/user/svn/new' does not exist (the folder name is actually "new stuff"

Svn version is 1.7.10 in case this information has any relevancy. I've seen some suggested solutions in other posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425592/problem-facing-in-adding-folder-having-space) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071857/how-do-i-svn-add-all-unversioned-files-to-svn)) but I keep getting same errors. Anyone knows any other solutions to achieve this from within a sh script?

Comment: I'm not a bash guru so not sure if it's relevant but... Does `svn add --force .` work from the command line?

Comment: No, as I wrote in the description, it throws error E125001 if a new folder or file exists that contains a space in the name.

Comment: I have tried to add folder with space but didn't meet the issue. Perhaps you can try to clean up your working copy.

Comment: Did you try also from debian cli using svn add --all? Adding manually files also works for me (e.g. svn add "folder space") but I need it to work with svn add . (all)